# How to randomly select items from a list for random times

Tags: python-3.x, list, random

```
 mal = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]
num_to_select = randint(1,4)                
list_of_random_items = random.sample(mal , num_to_select)
first_random_item = list_of_random_items[0]
second_random_item = list_of_random_items[1] 
print(second_random_item)
print(first_random_item)
```

I searched some similar questions here and tried to edit the answers a bit but doesnt work.

I want to select random items for random times like;

python randomly chose the number 4

printed randomly 4 items from list

Thank you.

Comment: What actual research have you done before asking us? Have you tried to code a solution on your own? If so, please show us and explain why it doesn't do what you want it to do.

Comment: @HampusLarsson Okay, I am sorry I am new here. Now I am editing

Comment: What is the actual question here? Your code already seems to do all the things you want it to do.

Comment: It always prints two items from the list, even though I used  randit(1,4) for num_to_select. My aim is to print 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 random items from the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code already does what you want it to do. It calls `random.randint` to get a random number between 1 and 4. It then uses that random number to use `random.sample` retrieve that number of items.

`random.sample` returns a `list` that contains all of the values it's extracted. Because you cant know beforehand how large (or small) this list is going to be, the best bet is to iterate over the list dynamically, and print the values inside.

I've change your code to do just that here:

```
import random

mal = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]

num_to_select = random.randint(1, 4)
list_of_random_items = random.sample(mal, num_to_select)

for item in list_of_random_items:
    print(item)
```